# Updating value according to time

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i created a simple jackpot game. I completed the game, but my current problem is replenishing the coins everyday. I'm giving 10 coins per day, and the update should be at 9am. The problem is i don't know when to store the firstPlayedDate it. This is what I have been trying so far.

```
   public DateTime firstPlayedDate
   {
     get
    {
        CoinTracker firstPlayedEntry = _db.CoinTrackers.Where(u => u.FbId == fbId).OrderByDescending(u => u.CoinTimer).FirstOrDefault();
        return firstPlayedEntry == null ? new DateTime() : firstPlayedEntry.CoinTimer;
    }
   }

   public int AvailableDailyCoins
   {
     get
     {   
        return (DateTime.UtcNow.Date - firstPlayedDate.Date).Days > 0 ? 10 : 0;
     }
   }
```

One way i thought of was, everytime the player has 10 coins, i store the firstPlayedDate. Any other ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not give coins out based on a timer running in the client, if this is what you are thinking. This would allow the most basic of cheats. Anyone can modify the code running in the browser to give themselves rewards using a tool like fiddler.

Instead I would store lastActiveTimestamp in the users profile on the server and either use a cron job to iterate through the userlist awarding coins as necessary at the given time, or, I prefer, don't actually even give the reward at 9am - just calculate their reward due when their account is next active by reading lastActiveTimestamp and calculating the timespan from Datetime.Now().

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: heyy...thanks for the idea, i can roughly figure it out...i didn't thought of that...

Comment: @GopinathKoothaperumal : great, its late here, I was hoping I was still making sense :) This idea goes for anything in your game that might be valuable to the player as well, enhancers, inventory items and the like - if its allocated in the browser using javascript it can be modified by the user.